# Installable 3js application

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to deploy threejs app onto a VR device but as a standalone application. So I would want to deploy the application on the device without any need for internet access, so the application is not deployed on the server but on the device itself Is it possible?

Wanted to know if above was possible or will I have to shift to unity